# GCloud Bucket Storage Public Permission Exception

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I'm trying to add `allUsers` user to one of my buckets with a condition. But it throws an exception and I don't know what is the problem.

My bucket uses `uniform` bucket-level access control. I follow these steps:

1. Click Permission
2. Add Members
3. New Members (`allUsers`)
4. Select a role `Storage Object Viewer`
5. Add condition `resource.name.startswith('{my pattern}')`
6. Click Save

And I get `IAM policy update failed - backend error.`

Do you have any idea why am I getting this exception?

For more detail:
I have 4 different folders(I mean virtual folders) in my root directory. 
one of them starts with my pattern. The bucket has a lot of files but I tried the same changes for an empty bucket, nothing changed!
[image: condition][image: allUsers][image]

Answer (score 0):

I just reproduced this and in effect, I wasn't able to set a condition to allUsers in my bucket but I was able to set conditions for specific users. Setting conditions to allUsers is not supported, you must specify a valid user or group

Comment: It's so strange then. I followed the documentation steps to do this.

Comment: Can you share with us the document that you followed and specify the part where this procedure is used to set conditions for allUsers?

Comment: I followed this website. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public?hl=tr
There isn’t any information about conditions on this page. 
If conditions are not valid for allUser, Do you have any advice for making this? 
I’m planning to create one more bucket for non-public files. Does that sound correct?

Comment: This may be a good approach but it depends on how you handle your files. If you are creating your files dynamically you can also use fine-grained permissions to make public only certain files. Another possible option for this approach is to use a Cloud Function triggered by storage events. But again this will depend on your workflow